# Setting up notifications for a Flutter PWA

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

Trying to set up Firebase Cloud Messaging for a Flutter PWA but I don't know how to show the notifications. The PWA installs on a mobile phone just like a native app from the browser, so I would like to have mobile notifications. When app is closed tapping on the notification would open it and so on. Not looking for `showDialog` or anything like that.

I set up a `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file in the `web` directory

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-messaging.js");

firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage((message) => {
    console.log("onBackgroundMessage", message);
});
```

And imported it in `index.html`

```
<body>
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function (ev) {

        _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
          serviceWorker: {
            serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
          }
        }).then(function (engineInitializer) {
          return engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
        }).then(function (appRunner) {
          return appRunner.runApp();
        });

        navigator.serviceWorker.register('firebase-messaging-sw.js');
        var serviceWorkerUrl = 'flutter_service_worker.js?v=' + serviceWorkerVersion;
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

I also have these in the `main.dart` file

```
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
      print('Message data: ${message.data}');

      if (message.notification != null) {
        print('Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification}');
      }
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published!');
    });
```

I'm able to get the fcmToken and save it to Firestore ... and when I send a test notification I see the print messages from the above listener ... but don't know how to create the notification. I am only interested in the mobile notification, no in-app notification is required. Just the top bar notification.